# How do I obtain all the realmObjects from a realmList which is within another realmList?

Tags: android, realm

sorry if the question is not very clear. Let me try to develop on that here.
This is my structure.

```
public class User extends RealmObject{
  ...
  RealmList<Tags> userTags;
}

public class Tags extends RealmObject{
  ...
  RealmList<Results> tagResults;
}

public class Results extends RealmObject{
  ...
}
```

In one of my activities, I want to obtain all the **Tags** and all the containing **Results** from a specific **User**. For example:

```
user1 -> tag1 -> result1
              -> result2
      -> tag2 -> result3
              -> result4
```

The desired result should be result1, result2, result3, result4.

Right now I am doing it manually

```
...
RealmList<Results> tagResults = new RealmList<>;
RealmList<Tags> userTags= user1.getTags();
for (Tags tag : userTags)
{
  tagResults.addAll(tag.getResults());
}
mRealmAdapter = new RealmResultsAdapter(this, tagResults);
```

Is there any other way to obtain the desired result without doing it manually?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT:** Realm 3.5.0 added inverse relationships, so you should do this:

```
public class User extends RealmObject{
  ...
  RealmList<Tags> userTags;
}

public class Tags extends RealmObject{
  ...
  @LinkingObjects("userTags")
  private final RealmResults<User> tagOfUsers = null;

  RealmList<Results> tagResults;
}

public class Results extends RealmObject{
  @LinkingObjects("tagResults")
  private final RealmResults<Tags> resultsOfTags = null;

  ...
}
```

And

```
RealmResults<Tags> tags = realm.where(Tags.class).equalTo("tagOfUsers.userId", userId).findAll(); // has results
```

---

**PRE-3.0.0  ANSWER:**

Due to that we're still waiting on [inverse relationships (backlinks)](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/607), I'd set up the RealmObjects like this

```
public class User extends RealmObject{
  ...
  @PrimaryKey
  long id;

  RealmList<Tags> userTags;
}

public class Tags extends RealmObject{
  ...
  @PrimaryKey 
  long id; 

  User user;

  @Index
  long userId;

  RealmList<Results> tagResults;
}

public class Results extends RealmObject {
  User user;

  @Index
  long userId;

  Tags tag;

  @Index
  long tagId;
  ...
}
```

Then

```
RealmResults<Results> results = realm.where(Results.class).equalTo("userId", userId).findAll();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @EpicPandaForce. I was thinking something similar. It's a pity Realm team have not implemented yet, it would be very handy. Thanks again for your quick answer. ;)

Comment: Yeah, the current in-progress thing is the ObjectStore integration, multi-process support, then fine-grained notifications :) personally I'd love some `RealmList<String>`, and after that backlinks would be nice

Comment: Yeah, I would also like to see RealmList<String>. Now, I am using my own realmString objects. Thanks again.

Comment: Actually, Realm 3.5.0 added backlinks, and `RealmList<String>` is coming in like 2 weeks with Realm 4.0.0.